# Error when trying to run inference using TFlite

Tags: tensorflow-lite

I've custom trained ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8_3 with my data and exported the model and I'm able to do inferencing .
im using tensorflow 2.6 and now I want to convert the model to tflite to run it on mobile .I've used the code below to convert the model to tflite and the code run and a tflite model is saved successfully .

```
    converter=tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(PATH_TO_SAVED_MODE1L)
    converter.optimizations=[tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
    converter.target_spec.supported_ops=[tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
    tflite_model=converter.convert()
    with open('C:/Users/CX/Desktop/model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
      f.write(tflite_model)
```

Now im trying to test with some with images using the code below :

```
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
#interpreter.allocate_tensors()
path=r"C:\t3"
for file in pathlib.Path(path).iterdir():

   img = cv2.imread(r"{}".format(file.resolve()))
   print(np.shape(img))
   img = img.reshape(1,img.shape[0],img.shape[1],3) 
   print(np.shape(img))
   img = img.astype(np.uint32)

   vv= np.array(img, dtype=np.uint8)
   interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['shape_signature'],img)
   interpreter.invoke()
```

Im getting the error :

```
TypeError: SetTensor(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: tensorflow.lite.python.interpreter_wrapper._pywrap_tensorflow_interpreter_wrapper.InterpreterWrapper, arg0: int, arg1: handle) -> object

Invoked with: <tensorflow.lite.python.interpreter_wrapper._pywrap_tensorflow_interpreter_wrapper.InterpreterWrapper object at 0x000001E4D88E38F0>, array([ 1, -1, -1,  3])
```

here is the details from the interpreter.get_input_details() fucntion :

```
[{'name': 'serving_default_input_tensor:0', 'index': 0, 'shape': array([1, 1, 1, 3]), 'shape_signature': array([ 1, -1, -1,  3]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.uint8'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
```

==================
and interpreter.get_output_details()

```
[{'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:6', 'index': 462, 'shape': array([    1, 12804,     4]), 'shape_signature': array([    1, 12804,     4]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}, {'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:0', 'index': 1594, 'shape': array([1, 1]), 'shape_signature': array([ 1, -1]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}, {'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:5', 'index': 1559, 'shape': array([1]), 'shape_signature': array([1]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}, {'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:7', 'index': 482, 'shape': array([    1, 12804,    56]), 'shape_signature': array([    1, 12804,    56]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}, {'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:1', 'index': 1647, 'shape': array([1, 1, 1]), 'shape_signature': array([ 1, -1, -1]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}, {'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:2', 'index': 1629, 'shape': array([1, 1]), 'shape_signature': array([ 1, -1]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}, {'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:4', 'index': 1576, 'shape': array([1, 1]), 'shape_signature': array([ 1, -1]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}, {'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:3', 'index': 1612, 'shape': array([1, 1, 1]), 'shape_signature': array([ 1, -1, -1]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
```

Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to resize input tensors and the given shape in the set_tensor should not have -1 value instead of the fixed shape value.

Comment: Thank you ,but that's the model signature .I cannot control that .The reshape should have  added extra dimension as per the model input requirement .I tried to resize ,the issue still there .I want to mention that everything works fine with the original model before converting to tflite.

Comment: any help please ?